# Cannot find resource files in JAR when running as a module

Tags: java, jar, resources, java-module

I develop desktop applications as a Java module with `Java 16.0.2` and `JavaFX 16` and put it into a JAR. When I run the JAR as a module the `ClassLoader.getResource(String name)` method can find the resource files in the resource root only. Resource files located in a directory within the resource root cannot be found.

I show an example.

The project file system is standard:

```
├───java
│   │   module-info.java
│   │
│   └───org
│       └───example
│           └───java_module_resource_issue
│                   JavaModuleResourceIssue.java
│
└───resources
    │   foo.xml
    │
    └───bar
            boo.xml
```

module-info.java:

```
module org.example.java_module_resource_issue {
}
```

JavaModuleResourceIssue.java:

```
package org.example.java_module_resource_issue;

public class JavaModuleResourceIssue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(JavaModuleResourceIssue.class.getClassLoader().getResource("foo.xml"));
        System.out.println(JavaModuleResourceIssue.class.getClassLoader().getResource("bar/boo.xml"));
    }
}
```

When I run the JAR as a module:

```
>java --module-path . --module org.example.java_module_resource_issue
jar:file:///D:/Projects/java_module_resource_issue/./JavaModuleResourceIssue-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/foo.xml
null
```

When I run the JAR as a JAR:

```
>java -jar JavaModuleResourceIssue-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
jar:file:/D:/Projects/java_module_resource_issue/JavaModuleResourceIssue-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/foo.xml
jar:file:/D:/Projects/java_module_resource_issue/JavaModuleResourceIssue-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/bar/boo.xml
```

The content of the JAR:

```
│   foo.xml
│   module-info.class
│
├───bar
│       boo.xml
│
├───META-INF
│       MANIFEST.MF
│
└───org
    └───example
        └───java_module_resource_issue
                JavaModuleResourceIssue.class
```

The question is not primarily how I can access the resource files. I've already found a solution for myself.  The problem that library methods also uses the `ClassLoader.getResource()` method.
For example if I add a CSS for a stylesheet list of a Scene, I can do it by filename only, and the StyleManager cannot find the file with the `getResource()` method. (It would be nice if I could add these files by URL.)

The problem doesn't occur if I don't use modules, but there is a warning then that it is an unsupported way of using JavaFX.

Is it a bug in implementation of `getResource()`?

Comment: `java --module-path . -cp .:resources --add-modules org.example.java_module_resource_issue   org.example.java_module_resource_issue.JavaModuleResourceIssue` does it for me. You need to set the classpath too

Comment: @g00se Thanks for the tip! It works for me exactly these ways:  `java -cp JavaModuleResourceIssue-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -p . -m org.example.java_module_resource_issue`  or  `java -cp* -p . -m org.example.java_module_resource_issue`